# Natural deduction proof of $ \neg q \Rightarrow p$ using $ (p \Rightarrow q) \Rightarrow p$

Tags: logic, natural-deduction

I am having some trouble completing this proof, I have attached an image of my best attempt so far but I am unsure if it is correct.

I would like some help on where I have gone wrong and some ideas on what I can do to get a correct derivation. We have the implication rules for $\vee, \wedge, \Rightarrow, \neg$.

Thought process:

Breaking down the question from the bottom, we can assume $\neg q $ and must now prove $p$. I assumed $\neg (p \Rightarrow q) $ and derived $p \wedge \neg q$ and attempted proof by contradiction. I can produce a proof of this derivation separately (it should just use De Morgan's law and rewriting implication).

Notes:

On line 4, I state that I derived this from the subproof.
On line 8, this is a PC using (5-7)
On line 11 and 15, they are just restatements of previously found values.

Any help would be appreciated.

For convenience, here is the LaTeX code using fitch.sty by Peter Selinger:

$$
\begin{nd}

\hypo {1} {(p \Rightarrow q) \Rightarrow p}
\open
\hypo {2} {\neg q}
\open
\hypo {3} {\neg (p \Rightarrow q)}
\open
\hypo {4} {p \wedge \neg q}
\have {5} {p}  \oe {4}
\open
\have {6} {\neg p }
\have {7} {F} \ne {5-6}
\close
\have {8} {q}
\have {9} {\neg q} \oe {4}
\have {10} {F} \ne {8-9}
\close
\have {11} {F}
\close
\have {12} {p \Rightarrow q}  \ii {(3-11)}
\have {13} {p} \ie {(1, 12)}
\close
\have {14} {\neg q \Rightarrow p} \ii {1 - 13}
\close
\have {15} {\neg q \Rightarrow p}
\end{nd}
$$

Comment: What was your motivation for assuming ¬ (p⇒q) ? Instead, try assuming ¬ p, and try a proof by contradiction from there.

Comment: Indeed.$\small\def\fitch#1#2{\quad\begin{array}{|l}#1\\\hline#2\end{array}}\qquad\fitch{(p\to q)\to p}{\fitch{\lnot q}{\fitch{\lnot p}{~\vdots\\\bot}\\\lnot\lnot p\\~p}\\\lnot q\to p}$

Comment: One possible approach: observe that the hypothesis $(p \rightarrow q) \rightarrow p$ is also the hypothesis of Peirce's law; therefore, by Peirce's law, you can conclude $p$.  Then, $\lnot q \rightarrow p$ is trivial.